# Should functions like this have Unit Tests?

Tags: php, unit-testing, tdd, phpunit

I've written a webapp using PHP and JS that's kind of working now, and decided that I should learn about unit testing and implement it now while cleaning up my code.

I am confused as to what should be unit tested. Every PHPUnit tutorial I've seen tests getters, setters, counts items in arrays. The site I am working on has say a page that displays photos. A user can Like a photo or Add it to his Favorites. PHP is mainly used in the site as an API layer to the clientside running backbone.js.

How should I write unit tests for these functions? A function (shown below) grabs $_GET data sent to it via AJAX and insert some rows into the database. It does not contain any setters, getters, or counts anything and is not a class. Should it even have a unit test?

An example of a unit test that I can write for these functions will be really awesome! :)

```
/**
 * Create new Set and add item to it
 *  @return  void
 */ 
public function action_create_set() {
    // Get data from user
    $user_id = Input::get('user_id');
    $post_id = Input::get('post_id');
    $set_name = Input::get('set_name');

    // Create new set
    $data = array(
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'name' => $set_name
    );
    $set_id = DB::table('sets')->insert_get_id($data);

    // Add item to newly created set
    DB::query("INSERT IGNORE INTO posts_sets (post_id, set_id, user_id)
        VALUES ($post_id, $set_id, $user_id)");

    // Change `created_at` & `updated_at` col of 'sets'
    $data = array(
        'created_at' => DB::raw('NOW()'),
        'updated_at' => DB::raw('NOW()')
        );
    DB::table('sets')
        ->where('id', '=', $set_id)
        ->update($data);
}
```

For this first function, my impression is that a test can be written to check that those 3 variables `$user_id, $post_id, $set_name` have to contain data. I feel that there should be a test to check that the 2 `insert` queries work, but I also think that the functions that insert the rows are provided by the PHP framework and have already been thoroughly tested so no further unit testing is required.

Another guess is the test should provide the 3 variables to the function, then check whether the new rows have been inserted into the 2 tables, but wouldnt this be considered an integration test?

---

Here's a function that takes input from a user via AJAX, then returns the result in JSON format. Should PHPUnit handle this kind of API functions? Or should the unit testing be done on the clientside?

```
/**
 * Get items Liked by user
 * @return array
 */
public function action_likes() {

    $user_id = Input::get('user_id');

    $likes = DB::table('likes')
                ->join('posts', 'posts.id', '=', 'likes.post_id')
                ->where('likes.user_id', '=', $user_id)
                ->get();

    return json_encode($likes);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

At first, you should make an "unit" to be tested.

Your current implementation puts everything into a function.  Such code is difficult to test.

At first, I recommend split it into 3 parts.

The first part process `$_GET` and compose an internal expression.
Then the second part saves it into the database.
At last, the third part receives the object in database, and render the response.

If you split it up, the second and thrid function will become testable.

This is too naive, but maybe worth as your first step.  If you interested, please search for MVC.

Answer (score 1):

> Another guess is the test should provide the 3 variables to the
>   function, then check whether the new rows have been inserted into the
>   2 tables, but wouldnt this be considered an integration test?

General note: When you start learning about unit testing and test automation in general you will quickly realize that terms like "unit test" and "integration test" are actually quite relative and very context dependant.

From your description of the action_create_set function it seems that you can treat it like a part of your web api layer. If you decide to write tests for this layer then yes, testing if this function actually transforms your database in the correct way is a good idea.

Is it unit testing? Well, one could argue that the answer is no because this function does "too many" things (transforming data from HTTP request, making database calls and if you test it by making fake http requests this generally involves your whole http handling stack).

On the other hand you are testing one single function of you web api that has one single and clearly defined responsibility in terms of the business logic of your application. That would be an argument for the positive answer.

I personally prefer the latter one but at the end of the day it doesn't really matter that much.

> Here's a function that takes input from a user via AJAX, then returns
>   the result in JSON format. Should PHPUnit handle this kind of API
>   functions? Or should the unit testing be done on the clientside?

It dependes on the situation. From the test automation purists point of view the perfect solution would be to test on both sides.

Server side tests should describe and test how your action_likes function behave in different situations:

- does it return empty set when no data is available?
- what happens if user_id is absent or in incorrect format?
- what is returned in a typical scenario?

Each of this tests should start with some preset data in the database and check the content of the JSON returned. That way you are testing your server API layer.

But testing client side code can also make sense. Most often than not successfully receiving data from an ajax call is supposed to have some side effects.

You can test for example that apropriate callbacks that should handle received data are actually called or some data structures reacts accordingly.

In this kind of tests you are not interacting with the real server but you're mocking AJAX requests and responses using js libraries designed for this purpose. There are many of them. My current preferences include [buster.js](http://busterjs.org/) which I find also very good for using in the continous integration environment.